# How to set text inside QLineEditor instantly

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt6

Here are my codes, for first file.

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from gui_file import YourCalculator
import time


class YourGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        self.calculator = YourCalculator()

        self.calculator.task_completed.connect(self.on_task_completed)

        button = QPushButton("Start Tasks")
        button.clicked.connect(self.start_tasks)
        button.setFixedSize(200, 20)

        self.line_editor = QLineEdit("hhh")
        self.line_editor.setFixedSize(200, 20)

        widget = QWidget(self)
        widget.setFixedSize(400, 600)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_editor)

    def start_tasks(self):
        self.calculator.task1()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.calculator.task2()
        time.sleep(1)
        self.calculator.task3()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_task_completed(self, message):
        print(message)
        self.line_editor.setText(message)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = YourGUI()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

For second file:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal


class YourCalculator(QObject):
    task_completed = pyqtSignal(str)

    def task1(self):
        self.task_completed.emit("Task 1 completed")

    def task2(self):
        self.task_completed.emit("Task 2 completed")

    def task3(self):
        self.task_completed.emit("Task 3 completed")
```

When I run this program, I got the figure below:

[Result after running program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDITv.png)

Once I click the button, and I get:

[Result after clicking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3dRZ.png)

However, what I really want is when I click the button, it should show the text inside QLineEditor as a sequence, like Task 1 completed -> Task 2 completed -> Task 3 completed. Now, it will only show the Task 3 completed after everything is over. So how can I get what I want? Do I need to use thread or multiprocessor or something?

I tried to add `time.sleep` inside my program, but it seems not work.

Comment: Functions such as `time.sleep()` are blocking and prevent the UI event loop to properly process events (including repainting widgets). I suppose that those `task` functions actually do some time consuming and CPU demanding computations, right?

Comment: I agree, but this is not key point. Currently, when I do these three tasks, only the final message can be displayed. How to overcome this? @musicamante

Comment: On the contrary, it is a major point. If those tasks are CPU bound, threading will probably have almost no benefit (the GIL prevents any thread "parallelism", unless the working thread temporarily returns control to the others); in fact, it can even worsen the situation. If not (for instance, file system access like copying large files, or waiting for a network reply), then threading will certainly help. In the first case, calling [`QApplication.processEvents()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) right after emitting the signal (or after `setText()`) is the only option.

Comment: Note that: 1. `processEvents()` only affects events in the thread that calls it, so if those `task` functions are called from another thread, it will have no result; 2. due to the way the event queue and some Qt object management works (for instance, with complex widgets dealing with internal layout management like scroll areas), it may still be not 100% reliable. If those tasks are very time consuming (more than a few seconds) and deeply demanding for the CPU, you should consider multiprocessing instead.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thx for you explanation. I understant a little bit now. Due to unfamiliar with the PyQt6 module, currently, seems I cannot work this problem out....

Comment: You probably can, but we need at least a more detailed explanation of what those `task` functions do, or, better, a valid [mre] (which doesn't mean that you need to provide your full code!). Note that your question is quite common, and will probably result in it being a duplicate of an existing one. Still, we must know more details about your specific issues, because, in its current form, what you're asking is quite broad, and dummy `doStuff` functions are almost always unhelpful: a lot can happen within those functions, and if we don't know that, we can hardly help.